# How to merge blocks of rows to single rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a dataframe like this, for example:

```
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
    0   8  9  2  1  6  2  6  8  6  3
    1   1  1  8  3  1  6  3  6  3  9
    2   1  4  3  5  9  3  5  9  2  3
    3   4  6  3  8  4  3  1  5  1  1
    4   1  8  5  3  9  6  1  7  2  2
    5   6  6  7  9  1  8  2  3  2  8
    6   8  3  6  9  9  5  8  4  7  7
    7   8  3  3  8  7  1  4  9  7  2
    8   7  6  1  4  8  1  6  9  6  6
    9   3  3  2  4  8  1  8  1  1  8
    10  7  7  5  7  1  4  1  8  8  6
    11  6  3  2  7  6  5  7  4  8  7
```

I would like to put rows to certain "blocks" of given length and the flatten them to single rows. So for example, if the block length would be `3`, the result here would be:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10 ...  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
2   8   9   2   1   6   2   6   8   6   3   1 ...   9   1   4   3   5   9   3   5   9   2   3
5   4   6   3   8   4   3   1   5   1   1   1 ...   2   6   6   7   9   1   8   2   3   2   8
8   8   3   6   9   9   5   8   4   7   7   8 ...   2   7   6   1   4   8   1   6   9   6   6
11  3   3   2   4   8   1   8   1   1   8   7 ...   6   6   3   2   7   6   5   7   4   8   7
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think need `reshape`:

```
n_blocks =3
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, n_blocks *df.shape[1]))
print (df)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  \
0   8   9   2   1   6   2   6   8   6   3 ...   1   4   3   5   9   3   5   9   
1   4   6   3   8   4   3   1   5   1   1 ...   6   6   7   9   1   8   2   3   
2   8   3   6   9   9   5   8   4   7   7 ...   7   6   1   4   8   1   6   9   
3   3   3   2   4   8   1   8   1   1   8 ...   6   3   2   7   6   5   7   4   

   28  29  
0   2   3  
1   2   8  
2   6   6  
3   8   7  

[4 rows x 30 columns]
```

Comment: @Gerardo Flores - Thank you

Comment: Anytime I want to answer you beat me to it. I guess you can say I'm your fan now haha

Comment: That won't work unless `len(df)` is divisible by `n_blocks`

Comment: @user1747134 - Yes, it depends of data, number of columns and rows.

Comment: @user1747134 - I am thinking about this solution, is possible specify number of column of final `Dataframe` ? Like in sample `30`. If `N` is not divisible like `N=17` (columns) last values should be replaced by NaNs?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, maybe someone comes up with a better one:

```
def toBlocks(df, blocklen):
  shifted = [df.shift(periods=p) for p in range(blocklen)]
  return pd.concat(shifted, axis=1)[blocklen-1:]
```

Comment: I try test it by `print (toBlocks(df, 3))` and maybe something wrong.